# Broadcast a basic event to all clients

Tags: node.js, socket.io, client

How would I go about broadcasting `alert("Hello World!");` on all clients currently avaible?

I have gone through these links:

https://socket.io/get-started/chat

https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/

https://socket.io/docs/v3/emit-cheatsheet/

And **NONE** of them helped. Can someone please help me?!

Solutions I have tried:

```
// Script.js:
var socket;

function onload(){
  socket = io();
}

function test(){
   socket.emit("broadcast");
}
socket.on('broadcast', function() {
    alert("Hello World!");
});
```

```
// index.js:
const express = require("express");
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const io2 = require("socket.io-client");

const directory = path.join(__dirname, "html");
const httpserver = http.Server(app);
const io = socketio(httpserver);

app.use(express.static(directory));
httpserver.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To broadcast a message to all connected clients from your server, you do:

```
io.emit('bulletin', someMsg);
```

To listen for that message in the client, you do this:

```
socket.on('bulletin', someMsg => {
    console.log(someMsg);
});
```

The message name `'bulletin'` can be anything you want it to be (any string that doesn't conflict with a built-in message name).

You cannot trigger a broadcast directly from the client.  But, you can send the server a custom message that you design and have the server, upon receipt of that message, then do a broadcast to all connected clients.

Comment: what file would this go in?

Comment: @BrycenWeeks - The client-side code goes with any of your client-side Javascript.  The server-side code goes anywhere you have access to the `io` variable that represents your socket.io server instance.

Comment: ah, thank you. You are so helpful.